# Disabling RecyclerView Item onClick while doing background job

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm doing an Android app using Kotlin. I want to disable onClick from RecyclerView while doing background task (API calls). After finish update then click should be abled. How can I do this ?

```
fun bind(job: PrintJobData, listener: OnHistoryListFragmentInteractionListener?) {

   itemView.setOnClickListener {

      listener?.onListFragmentInteraction(job)

   }
}

interface OnHistoryListFragmentInteractionListener {

    fun onListFragmentInteraction(item: PrintJobData)

}
```

Comment: use a loader while doing api call so that it prevent clicking on other view

Comment: Hi, i'm using SwipeRefreshLayout and its auto update ON. I need that. While update on if I click on any recyclerview item its opens up details page, and if I return to same recycler page server error message connection error socket closed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `itemView.setEnabled(false)` to disable the clicks, then call `setEnabled(true)` to re-enable the clicks.

For Kotlin I believe its `itemView.isEnabled = {false | true}`

Make sure these calls occur on the UI thread.  Example using your comment:

```
   private fun updateUsersJobs() 
   { 
     swipeContainer?.isRefreshing = true 
     
     itemView.isEnabled = false
    
     model?.updateUsersJobs(this, 
     { 
       activity?.runOnUiThread 
       { 
         swipeContainer?.isRefreshing = false 
         itemView.isEnabled = true
       } 
     }, 
     { error -> activity?.runOnUiThread 
       { 
         swipeContainer?.isRefreshing = false
         itemView.isEnabled = true
       }
     };
  }
```

Comment: How to disable recycle touch event when refresh works from this below code:  private fun updateUsersJobs() {
        swipeContainer?.isRefreshing = true
        model?.updateUsersJobs(this, {
            activity?.runOnUiThread {
                swipeContainer?.isRefreshing = false
            }
        }, { error ->
            activity?.runOnUiThread {
                swipeContainer?.isRefreshing = false

Comment: Above code not working for me. what about changing to databinding with live data and view model. Can anybody help how to do that way. steps to follow.